# Highcharts Columnrange Questions (multiple y-axes and column widths)

Tags: highcharts

I'm in the process of evaluating Highcharts as a replacement for our current platform, and have some questions about how we can replicate one of our existing charts:

[image: current chart image]

I've been able to recreate the basic floating stacked column chart, but need help with some of our specific features.

1) Is is possible to replicate the multiple y-axes with the columns displayed to the right of each within a single chart?  If not, I suppose we could do 3 charts next to one another - and draw our own titles above (and data table below).  If we go this route, is there a way to group all these elements in a single "container"?  We need to export these charts to images and need to end up with a single image that looks like the one attached.

2)  How would I create the inner box within each column?  Do I need to draw it myself, or can I create another column series with a border and transparent fill and somehow set the width of the column to be less than the width of the main columns (note that the number of columns on each chart is dynamic, so the column widths can't be a fixed size.  i.e. the inner box width needs to be a percentage of the main column width)?

3) Assuming #2 is possible, I could probably use the same technique to plot the horizontal line - just make the height 0 (or very small) and make the bar wider instead of smaller.  Is there a better way?

4) How do I get the x coordinates of the columns so we can align our data table under each column?

5) Can I separate the individual points within the column.  You'll notice in my jsfiddle, product 1 and product 2 are vertically aligned in the center of the column.  Can I spread them out within each column as the 2 points are in the screenshot?

Thanks in advance for advice on all or any of the above.

Mike

Comment: my basic floating bar chart is here: http://jsfiddle.net/mandream/7rJxr/9/

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use multiple yAxis, see the [example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes)

2) You can use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer) or mix column/column range and border parameter, [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cJm7d/)

```
plotOptions: {
        columnrange: {
            pointPadding:0.2,
            color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
            borderColor: '#303030'            
        }
    },
```

3) Use renderer, as above or scatter series with customied [marker](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.scatter.marker.symbol)

4) Column is shape in point.element.graphic, so you can extract it.

5) as far as I know, it is not possible